# make focus open a menu when it is hovering it

Tags: html

on this site:
http://www.dogslife.org.il/

when passing the focus with the TAB button when it gets to the menu area and go threw the button the menu dosn't open.

any suggestions on how to make itopen like it dose here (same theme):
http://www.magic-glass.co.il/

Answer (score 0):

Add :focus to your CSS where you use :hover, that will trigger it when it's focused with tab

Comment: can you please explain/give an example ?, i added ::focus { 
border: 1px solid #6e9fe4;
    }
to the CSS and when an element is focused it shows the border. but still it dosn't show the menu as open like in the other site.